# fs.WriteFile() returning NULL and not writing to JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have a Javascript file that writes data to my "sequence.json" file. However, I keep getting reiterations of **NULL** returned in my console. Then when I view my "sequence.json" file, it updates, but updates to `"\"i\": 99"` or whatever the last iterated number was based off `inputNum`. The JSON file also doesn't look like a JSON, it should look like an array of objects like this:

`[{"i":1,"addedSum":2},{ "i":2,"addedSum":4 }]`

Here is my code in order. it may have a lot of errors, this was my first attempt at something like this, so apologies if it's a bit messy.

**Required fs and used readFileSync():**

```
var fs = require("fs");
const data = fs.readFileSync("sequence.json");
var numberCount = JSON.parse(data);
let numberObj = JSON.stringify(numberCount);

let inputNum = 100;
```

`InitCount()` initializes the count and is suppose to push `i` and `addedSum` to my "sequence.json" file. Instead, it returns iterations of **NULL** with my sequence.JSON file only containing: `"\"i\": 99"`.

```
const InitCount = (inputNum) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < inputNum; i++) {
    let addedSum = i + i;
    console.log(i);
    let data = JSON.stringify(`"i": ${i}`, `addedSum:${addedSum}`);

    fs.writeFile("sequence.json", data, finished);
    function finished(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
};
```

`addCount()` is supposed to look at the last number in "sequence.JSON" and continue the count if `inputNum` is > than the last number in the array. Example: If the array is empty, and you input 100, the sequence.JSON file should reflect 100 objects. If you then were to input 200, then its function is supposed to identify that the last number in the "sequence.json" array, `i`, was 100, and continue the count up to 200, of course starting from 101, then add and write the new numbers onto "sequence.JSON".

```
function addCount(arr, inputNum) {
  let i = arr.length;
  for (i ? arr[i - 1].len + 1 : 0; i <= inputNum; i++) {
    let addedSum = i + i;
    let data = JSON.stringify(`"i": ${i}`, `addedSum:${addedSum}`);

    fs.writeFile("sequence.json", data, finished);
    function finished(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    addCount(numberObj, inputNum);
  }
}
return InitCount(inputNum);
```

**Update: Code returning error** `Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined`

```
const fs = require("fs");

let inputNum = 200;

async function readSequenceJSON() {
  let data = await fs.promises.readFile("numberLine.json");
  return JSON.parse(data);
}

function writeSequenceJSON(data) {
  let str = JSON.stringify(data);
  return fs.promises.writefile("numberLine.json", str);
}

async function nextSequence(inputNum) {
  let data = await readSequenceJSON();

  for (let i = 0; i <= inputNum; i++) {
    const addedSum = i + i; 
    // only push numbers whose frequencies are "in bounds" of num
    if (frequency <= inputNum) {
      data.push({ i, addedSum });
    }
  }

  function addValues(data, inputNum) {
    for (
      let i = data.length ? data[data.length - 1].i + 1 : 0;
      i <= inputNum;
      i++
    ) {
      const addedSum = i + i;
      data.push({ i, addedSum });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is attempting to start a whole bunch of `fs.writeFile()` operations such that they are ALL trying to write to the file at the same time.  This will clearly cause problems and conflicts.  It doesn't really make sense to be calling `fs.writeFile()` over and over on the same file in a loop because each new write will just overwrite what was previously written, even if you sequence them one at a time.

In addition, you're passing two strings to `JSON.stringify()` where the second string would be interpreted as a replacer which is supposed to be either a function or an array, but you're passing a string.  So, that doesn't make sense either.

Then, you appear to be calling `addCount()` recursively forever.  That also doesn't make sense.

I honestly cannot tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish with your sequence.json file so I'll offer a small tutorial on writing a new item to that sequence.

Let's suppose you have a `sequence.json` that initially contains:

```
[{"i":1,"addedSum":2}]
```

And, you want to find the last `i` and `addedSum` values in that array and create the next item in the sequence.  To do that, you would following these steps:

1. Read in the existing JSON
2. Parse it into a Javascript object
3. Using it as Javascript, get the last item in the array and look at the `i` and `addedSum` values there.
4. Create the new object you want to add to the end of the array and add it to the array
5. Convert the modified array to JSON and write to to your file.

Code here:

```
async function readSequenceJSON() {
     let data = await fs.promises.readFile('sequence.json');
     return JSON.parse(data);
}

function writeSequenceJSON(data) {
     let str = JSON.stringify(data);
     return fs.promises.writeFile('sequence.json', str);
}

async function nextSequence(input) {
      let data = await readSequenceJSON();

      // do some processing of data here to possibly add a new item
      // insert your code here, data is a Javascript object (no JSON)
      // data[data.length - 1] references the last object in the array
      // if that is key to your processing

      return writeSequenceJSON(data);
}

// how to call it
nextSequence(someInput).then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I was trying to implement the solution code above, how would I push items to my JSON? I'm used to javascript array methods like .push() so I'm not sure how to do it with this method. Thanks!

Comment: @KingMuze - Inside of `nextSequence()`, after the `readSequence()` line of code, `data` is just an array so you would just do `data.push(...)`.

Comment: I received this error in the console when attempting to push to data. 

TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
    at nextSequence (/Users/javontaymcelroy/Documents/initCount.js:21:12)

Here's that line of code:

  for (let i = 0; i <= inputNum; i++) {
    const addedNum = i + i;

    if (addedNum <= inputNum) {
      data.push(...{ i, addedNum });
    }
  }

Comment: Fixed that issue by converting added str to my pushes. But now getting this error: TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: @KingMuze - On what line of code are you getting that error `TypeError: object is not iterable`?  I don't think that error would come from any of the code in my answer.

Comment: ```Line 21:20 TypeError: i is not iterable at nextSequence.``` I have a forLoop where I have ```( let i = 0; i < inputNum; i++) ``` written there and then I try and push to my json:  ``` data.push(...i, frequency, str);``` Should my JSON be structured any particular way before initializing as well?

Comment: @KingMuze - You can't do `data.push(...i, frequency, str)` because `i` is a number and it's not something that can be iterated with `...`.  Perhaps what you meant was this: `data.push({i, frequency, str})` if you're trying to add an object with three properties named `i`, `frequency` and `str` to the array.  If not, then I need to know what you want in the array after the `.push()`.

Comment: Awesome that fixed it. But now ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined``` on line 6. It's like one bug after another... I'm just wanting to push an array of objects with numbers to a client-side backend for me to import into my frontend and continue working.

Comment: @KingMuze - I can't work with code I can't see.  Are you, by any chance, running an old version of nodejs?  `fs.promises` and `fs.promises.readFile` was added to nodejs in version 10.0.  Beyond that, you'd have to show your current code for me to help any further.

Comment: Just added the updated code at the end of the post.

Comment: @KingMuze - Change this `var fs = require("fs").promises;` to `const fs = require("fs");`.  You don't want to change the meaning of `fs` because your code references `fs.promises.readFile` and `fs.promises.writeFile`.

Comment: But when I changed that I get this ```TypeError: fs.promises.writefile is not a function``` What's up with all these errors?

Comment: @KingMuze - Proper spelling is `fs.promises.writeFile`.  That was my a typo in my answer (which I have corrected).

Comment: Wow, one little change, thank you so much! That did it!